# Bones with spline IK follow offset?

Tags: rigging, bones

I am new at this. I have a model of an elephant. I control the trunk with spline IK and I want the trunk to follow the offset of the spine but the bones of the trunk are locked to follow the spline, what can I do? Is there maybe a way to make the spline follow the spine bone? I attach some images.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this if you don't want to run into dependency cycles with Spline IK: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35442/7777

Comment: Thank you, seems like it depends on the version, but seems a god solution, I switched to just IK in this case.